# How do I explicitly calculate this indirect-speech-ish conversational implicature?

Tags: pragmatics

I'm self-studying pragmatics, and I stumbled upon [this exercise](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/linguistics-and-philosophy/24-903-language-and-its-structure-iii-semantics-and-pragmatics-spring-2005/assignments/ps4.pdf) on MIT OpenCourseWare:

> [from a text
> book by Chierchia & McConnell-Ginet]
>
> In each of the pairs below,
> sentence (a) conversationally implicates sentence (b). For each pair,
> provide a reason for thinking that the implication is not a
> truth-conditional entailment [consult Portner Section 11.1, pp.
> 203-205, and you class notes], and calculate the implicature as best
> you can, indicating where contextually specific premises need to be
> supplied.

I'm wondering how to provide a calculation for the implicature in (b):

> (2) a. I wonder what time it is.
>
> b. The speaker wants to be told what time it is by the addressee.

It seems to me that this has something to do with the Maxim of Relation/Relevance. But it is not clear to me how to provide a calculation in a rigorous style, as in [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/linguistics-and-philosophy/24-903-language-and-its-structure-iii-semantics-and-pragmatics-spring-2005/readings/grice_cheatsheet.pdf). The best I could come up with is, roughly (skipping some routine steps):

> 1. S can be assumed (by H) to observe Quality
> 2. S says "I wonder what time it is." From 1., S must really wonder what the time is.
> 3. S can be assumed to observe Relevance
> 4. From 2., 3., S's wondering what the time is must be relevant to the goal of the conversation.
> 5. S can be assumed to know that H observes the Co-operative Principle
> 6. From 5., S knows that H can and will contribute to the goal of the conversation.
> 7. From 4. and 6., H can assume that the goal, which S's wondering must be related to and must involve H, is for S to learn the time from H.
> 8. The usual stuff... (S lets H believes 7. etc etc. and so S implicates that S wants to be told the time by H)

What frustrates me is Step 7, because I feel this is not explicit enough. It is not obvious how the mere information that H must be involved in the goal of the conversation and the necessary relevance of S's statement can lead to the implicature. Am I missing something or this is the most explicit I can do?

I've searched everywhere. The best I closest find is [Leech 2014](https://books.google.co.th/books?id=cCyTAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA163&vq=i%20wonder&pg=PA163#v=onepage&q=i%20wonder%20what%20the%20time%20is%20when%20entering%20a%20room&f=false), which basically says that an I-wonder statement signals information gap, and shows that by Maxim of Quantity, but it is not clear at all how he goes from the mere statement to the desire for information.

Edit: [cross-posted on /r/linguistics](https://www.reddit.com/r/linguistics/comments/g26u7o/how_do_i_explicitly_calculate_this/)

Comment: If saying X in current circumstances ordinarily implies Y, then X implicates Y.  The basic implication here is a matter of the speaker's estimate of the speech situation and what he thinks is ordinary, so it will always be a matter of opinion.